# symantec endpoint vs. symantec protection agent

Tags: anti-virus, symantec

I made the upgrade and while my download speeds seem to improve SIGNIFICANTLY, I get an marked increased in periodic disk thrashing, more so than with Protection Agent.

What is your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symantec Endpoint Protection 11.x combines several functions including NAC, IDS and AV.  The Protection Agent has less functionality.  SEPP is the latest product and can be installed with all features or just what you require.

SEPP has had several major updates since release to address performance issues as well.

Perhaps SEPP requires some tuning?  What exact version are you using?